# Join 3 tables, aggregate over date field and subtract sum of two columns

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and the they have the following columns.

```
shipments: shipment_id (PK), shipment_date (date)

invoices: invoice_id (PK), shipment_id (FK), amount (float)

bills: bill_id (PK), shipment_id (FK), amount (float)
```

Each shipment may have multiple invoices and bills. The net revenue of a month is defined as the sum of all bill amounts subtracted from the sum of invoice amounts in that month (derived from shipment_date). While a whole shipment may span across multiple months, we're only concerned about net revenue of the month as an aggregate.

Is there a way to calculate net revenues of all the months (depending on the data) with a single SELECT query?

Ignore the database design. And I'm trying the following query.

```
SELECT
    u.`month`  AS `month`,
    FORMAT(SUM(u.`amount`),2) AS `net_revenue`
FROM
    (SELECT
        i.`amount` AS `amount`,
        DATE_FORMAT(s.`shipment_date`, "%m/%Y") AS `month`
    FROM
        `invoices` i
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `shipments` s
            ON s.`shipment_id` = i.`shipment_id`
    UNION
    SELECT
        (-1 * b.`amount`) AS `amount`,
        DATE_FORMAT(s.`shipment_date`, "%m/%Y") AS `month`
    FROM
        `bills` b
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `shipments` s
            ON s.`shipment_id` = b.`shipment_id`) u
GROUP BY u.`month`
ORDER BY u.`month` ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final query that worked, with help from Akina's comments.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(s.`shipment_date`, "%m/%Y") AS `month`,
    FORMAT(SUM(u.`amount`),2) AS `net_revenue`
FROM
    (SELECT
        `amount`,
        `shipment_id`
    FROM
        `invoices`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        (-1 * `amount`) AS `amount`,
        `shipment_id`
    FROM
        `bills`) u
    JOIN `shipments` s
        ON u.`shipment_id` = s.`shipment_id`
GROUP BY `month`
ORDER BY `month` ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble of posting the solution as an answer. Too bad Akina shied away from doing so himself :) On a different note, as far as I can see (maybe I'm missing something, not sure), your original query would be semantically equivalent to (and therefore producing the same results as) this if you replaced the left joins with inner joins and `UNION` with `UNION ALL`. (Depending on the nature of the data in the `amount` column in both `invoices` and `bills`, `UNION` might even work the same as `UNION ALL` in this specific case in terms of the results produced.)